# Preloaded Document based Desktop Application

Tags: java, python, nosql

I want to develop a desktop application that allows users to search through json files.
These files (around 50.000) are predefined. They should be shipped with the application itself.

My question is, what would be the best way to ship these documents with the application and at the same time allow users to search for documents containing certain values, e.g. in sql terms: show all documents where some json value within the document like %Example%.

I thought about using some kind of NoSQL solution, preloading the files into the db and bundle it with the app. I've looked at some solutions, but I'm not really sure which one would be best suited for my needs or if it's even the best approach.

Bottom line is, I can't have my users install a db on their system, that is way too complicated.

I'd prefer a solution suitable for java or python.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[You can use an embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), memory based database (like hsql) or a file-based database like sqlite.

Neither require any installation from your end users. You just have to package the libraries as part of your application install bundle (and of course, the engine itself).

If you are looking for a k/v store, then the good ol' [`Berkeley DB`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) should suffice.  If you are really looking for a "embedded NoSQL solution", try [MooDB](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/326).

Comment: I've actually thought about that before and yes it could be done that way, what I don't like about that approach is that they are both relational solutions - which in turn means I'd have to store every document as a string in a certain column or even worse, parse every single document and put the values in their respective columns. I was really hoping for a better solution. Basically I want to avoid the overhead of modifying the already existing documents as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo DB comes in an embeddable version: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/embedmongo.flapdoodle.de

I've used it for integration testing (mocking a Mongo server) and it works really well!

Anytime I read document and search, I also think of Solr: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/